# Best value for 'telephone' property in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, phone-number

I'm adding structured data to my web pages and I can't find a standard format to fill the value of "telephone" property.

I used the telephone property in different scopes: [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization), [`ContactPoint`](https://schema.org/ContactPoint) and [`Person`](https://schema.org/Person).

Example provided from schema.org in Microdata format:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <h1><span itemprop="name">Beachwalk Beachwear & Giftware</span></h1>
  Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">850-648-4200</span>
</div>
```

Example provided from schema.org in JSON-LD format:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Paris, France",
    "postalCode": "F-75002",
    "streetAddress": "38 avenue de l'Opera"
  },
  "email": "secretariat(at)google.org",
  "faxNumber": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 01",
  "telephone": "( 33 1) 42 68 53 00"
}
</script>
```

Example provided from Google (Corporate Contact)
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contact

> An internationalized version of the phone number, starting with the "+" symbol and country code (+1 in the US and Canada).

So **which is the best format** if my international prefix is +41 and my number is 987654321?

- 0041-98-7654321
- (+41) 98 76 54 321
- +41987654321 = Google style
- or what else?

Is there a standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

00 changes per country, that's why they introduced the +. So I'd count that out.

Different countries format numbers differently. i.e. dashes are a US thing. So I would avoid any formatting characters. They are also irrelevant to what you enter in, so if anything could break the number when auto dialling.

So I would go will just the digits people should enter:

+41987654321

Same goes with using phone numbers in links.

Comment: Thanks, everything makes sense.